# Using closest_level to change titles while using transition_levels from the package gganimate in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm using `transition_layers` from `gganimate` to create an animated plot with a title that updates at each layer. Here is a simple reproducible example with two layers.

```
library(gganimate)

## data
df = data.frame(x=c(0,1), 
                y=c(0,1))

## static plot
g = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  labs(title = '{closest_layer}')
g

## animated plot
gg = g +
  transition_layers(layer_names=c('Layer 1: Points', 
                                  'Layer 2: Line')) + 
  enter_fade()
a = animate(gg, nframes = 50, end_pause = 20)
a
```

It works as expected to start, but then at the end of the animation, the title changes back to 'Layer 1: Points' too soon (while still showing the second layer, and before the animation restarts). How can I make the title stay on "Layer 2" while the second layer is showing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.  Using `next_layer` instead of `closest_layer` does the trick.

```
library(gganimate)

## data
df = data.frame(x=c(0,1), 
                y=c(0,1))

## static plot
g = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  labs(title = '{closest_layer}')
g

## animated plot
gg = g +
  transition_layers(layer_names=c('Layer 1: Points', 
                                  'Layer 2: Line')) + 
  enter_fade()
a = animate(gg, nframes = 50, end_pause = 20)
a
```

[image]